# Realm order object by date inside of a list of dates

Tags: swift, realm

So I have the following objects

```
class Chat: Object {
    dynamic var chatID = ""
    var participants = List<Friend>()
    var messages = List<Message>()

    /// Set the primary key
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "chatID"
    }
}

class Message: Object {
    dynamic var chat: Chat!
    dynamic var from: Friend!
    dynamic var message = ""
    dynamic var date = Date()
    dynamic var isRead: Bool = false
}
```

Now I obtain a list of all the chats that have been created. When I have the chats I want to be able to order them based on the last message. So what I need to do is order de list of chats by the date in the list of messages.

The chat which contains the message with the newest date needs to be on at the top and so on.

I've tried to order the list as follows
`realmManager.chatResults.sorted(byKeyPath: "messages.date", ascending: false)` but that throws the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid key path for sort',
>   reason: 'Cannot sort on 'messages.date': sorting on key paths that
>   include a to-many relationship is not supported.'

I currently can't figure out how I would go about fixing this. Does someone know how I could achieve the correct sort behaviour?

Comment: What error do you get? On first sight, it looks like a typo if chatResults is of type Chat. `messages` doesn't have a property `date`, since it is a list and not a single `Message` object.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I updated the answer to include the error that it throws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access a property of a single instance on a list, in particular you are trying to sort a `List<Message>` collection based on a property of a single `Message` instance.

If you want to sort `Chat` instances, first you have to sort `Chat.messages` and then sort by the last message. To mitigate that error you could use Swift's built in `sorted` function together with that of Realm.

```
let sortedChats = realm.objects(Chat.self).sorted{
    guard let currentLatestDate = $0.messages.sorted(byKeyPath: "date",ascending: false).first?.date, let nextLatestDate = $1.messages.sorted(byKeyPath: "date",ascending: false).first?.date else {return false}
    return currentLatestDate > nextLatestDate
}
```

The code has been tested in a playground and returns the `Chat` instances of your `Realm` sorted by the date of their latest `Message` in descending order.

Comment: I wrote something similar just now the only problem is that it will return an array of chats. I actually would like to order the `Result` list itself. Would you  have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, Realm's `sorted` function doesn't support sorting by closures, so this is not possible. However, unless for some reason you need to expose the self-updating nature of `Results`, I don't see any reason why `Array` wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: Let's say I would add a `lastMessageDate` object to the chat class. I could then use `let chatResults: Result<Chat> = realm.objects(Chat.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "lastMessageDate", ascending: false)` without any problems

Comment: By adding a new property to your Realm model it is possible, you are right. But again, you should think about why do you really need a `Result` collection instead of an `Array` and if it really is worth storing an otherwise useless piece of information for in your database.

Comment: well I guess I could use an array only thing is that I would need to fill the `Array` at multiple different points in the applications. where right now I don't have to do anything like that

Comment: As I sad before, if you use the self-updating functionality of Results, than stick to it. Unless you have a huge (millions of messages) dataset, storing an extra object reference shouldn't make a difference in performance/storage space.